# Regex for paginated URLs

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to work out a regex pattern to match URL's.

I currently have URL structures like so

`walks/category/catname`

`walks/category/catname/P12`

`walks/category/catname/P24`

I want to be able to match them and replace them so they end up like so

`walks/catname`

`walks/catname/p2`

`walks/catname/p3`

(where catname is a variable)

So far I had

`/walks/category/(.*)` to `/walks/$1`

Which seems to work for the first page of results, but obviously not for the paginated ones.

I'm ab bit stuck so any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not obvious that the pagination layer is not included in your `(.*)` bit of regex.  It should be, if you are sending paginated URLs like `/walks/category/catname/P13` into the regex `/walks/category/(.*)`.  If you aren't, and are only sending base URLs like `/walks/category/catname/` then the pages aren't even there to be regex matched in the first place, so you can't expect to change `/walks/category/catname/` to `/walks/catname/p10` because the regex can't see anything about `/p10` anywhere in the given URL.  If the full paginated URL's **are** being passed to regex, it should match.

Comment: Thats what I thought, and thats what is happening. Just the base URL's. Wasn't sure how to include the pagination variable.

Comment: In that case, I suggest asking another question which is more accurate to your circumstances.  Now it's a matter of how to pass paginated URL's into the regex, assuming that's still the method you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of like

Find `walks/.*?(/catname.*)`
Replace `walks$1`

Construct the regex to insert the catname variable
var regex = `'walks/.*?(/'` + vCatname + `'.*)'`

before:

```
walks/category/catname

walks/category/catname/P12

walks/category/catname/P24
```

after:

```
walks/catname

walks/catname/P12

walks/catname/P24
```

Comment: catname is a variable that changes.

Comment: @Bango - Added a note for a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm still not quite sure what's happening on this. Also the pagination number needs to change. That woudlnt happen here, right?

Comment: Pagination number ? If you are sequence replacing the ending, for example `P`##, that would have to, not only be optionally matched, but you'd need a callback for the replacement side for the _numberic sequencing_ logic.  This all depends on what language the regex is run from. Generally, the regex would be `walks/.*?(/catname.*?)((?:/p\d+)?)` So, if capture group 2 has length, construct the replacement in the callback with the sequence number like `if (length $2) replace = 'walks$1' + '/p' + sequence++;` or something.

Comment: Also, to insure the pagination (or not, since it was switched to `.*?` lazy) is to be matched at the end, you'd need to add the EOS anchor, like `walks/.*?(/catname.*?)((?:/p\d+)?)$`